# Tool for checking unused CSS selectors?

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, stylesheet

I know there is an extension called Dust-Me Selectors for Firefox and also that it doesn't look at dynamic HTML generated by JavaScript.

I'm looking for tool(s) that can identify all unused selectors from a stylesheet, attached to several pages, with all the JavaScript running and checking selectors?
The only option I know right now for this is manually checking files and finding unused selectors :(

In IDE's - I believe NetBeans provides a warning message when writing Java code, if a library is not under use. Without an IDE (NetBeans, Eclipse, Dreamweaver, etc) plugin to search for the selectors what are my options?

Also, is there a tool to check for unused selectors in the same file. I mean if all the JS, HTML and CSS code is in the same file.

Comment: That isn't really possible; you cannot predict what selectors are used by arbitrarily complicated Javascript.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that http://unused-css.com will do exactly what you want.

https://github.com/geuis/helium-css can help

as well as:  http://razorfast.com/2010/11/21/announcing-cssess-the-bookmarklet-that-finds-unused-css-selectors/

Comment: I tired out Helium... I liked how easy it was to find unused selectors...
Thanks for the Answer...