# Huge Css file with huge numbers of unsed rules

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool for checking unused CSS selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957881/tool-for-checking-unused-css-selectors)

I am working on a big project that was work on many people before me and now the CSS file is very big more than 4000 line there is many unused css rules i was trying firebug plugin CSS usage but i have to check page by page and compare what use here and not used there while its only one big CSS file is there any web site that can help me find unused CSS rules much better

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957881/tool-for-checking-unused-css-selectors

Comment: i cant because i didn't have enough reputation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In the chrome console you have the "Audits" tab. There you click in "Run" and shows you a result with unused rules.
2. http://code.google.com/intl/es/speed/page-speed/download.html this is a plugin for firefox and chrome

EDIT:
Here you have two tools to minimize css

1. http://tools.w3clubs.com/cssmin/
2. http://www.cleancss.com/