# Is there a tool to check if i have css tags i don't need?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool for checking unused CSS selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957881/tool-for-checking-unused-css-selectors)

So, I'm wondering is there something like a tool (online maybe?) that would check some html file (or site) and tell you which css tags you aren't using in your html, but you do have them in a CSS file?
This would be of a great help to me as I just started working on someone elses code which is honestly a mess - a css file being 2k lines long.

Anyways, appreciate your help!

Comment: If you're into front-end web-development, consider switching to the WebStorm IDE. It implements that functionality. Read here: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/index.html#HTML_CSS

Comment: just be sure before removing the rule, that it is not being added dynamically through javascript ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at DustMe Firefox extention: http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it in the browser, I recommend

https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/css-usage/